# How to use Shiny inputs to Filter Datatable that has been edited?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, datatables

I'm stumped on a three part process:

1. I'm trying to filter what is displayed to a dataTable via Shiny inputs (in the real app there would be dozens of these).
2. Then, I'd like to edit cell values in the DT.
3. Finally, I'd like to be able to change the filters and keep the edited cell values.

The example app below does 1 and 2, but not 3. After I make an edit AND click the only_johns checkbox, the dataTable displays the original data.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "demo")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
              downloadButton("downloadResults","Download Results"),
              checkboxInput("only_johns", "only_johns")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = 'admin', class = 'active', 
      fluidRow(
        box(
          dataTableOutput('userTable'), width = 6
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'admin function test', header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  #1
  start.df <- reactiveValues(data=NA)
  start.df$data <- data.frame(userName = rep(c("John","Ida","Mike"),20),
                    id = 1:60, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  

  #2  temp display filters df
  display.df <- reactiveValues(data=start.df)
  observe({
    
    temp <- isolate(start.df$data)
    if (input$only_johns) {
      
    display.df$data <- temp[temp$userName == "John",]
    } else {
      display.df$data <- temp
    }
  })
  
# Display editable datatable
  output$userTable <- renderDataTable({
    req(display.df$data)
    DT::datatable(isolate(display.df$data),
                  editable = TRUE,
                  rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  ###Tracking Changes###

  proxy = dataTableProxy('userTable')
  observe({
    DT::replaceData(proxy, display.df$data, rownames = FALSE, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$userTable_cell_edit, {
    display.df$data <<- editData(display.df$data, input$userTable_cell_edit, rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  
  output$downloadResults <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste("userTest.csv", sep = "")},
    content = function(file){write.csv(start.df$data, file, row.names = FALSE)}
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I wish I could be of more help. I think the `resetPaging = FALSE` would work but only if you include `isolate(view.df())` (which when included causes other problems, such as the table not updating when the checkbox is selected). I hope you can find a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far you only update the `diplay.df$data`, but you need to update the original `start.df$data`. I've included this in my solution, to find the correct row irrespective of the current filtering, I've introduced the column `row_id` that is hidden in the DT. Also, I've simplified your code a bit.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "demo")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    downloadButton("downloadResults","Download Results"),
    checkboxInput("only_johns", "only_johns")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = 'admin', class = 'active', 
      fluidRow(
        box(
          dataTableOutput('userTable'), width = 6
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'admin function test', header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  #1
  start.df <- reactiveValues(data=NA)
  start.df$data <- data.frame(userName = rep(c("John","Ida","Mike"),20),
                              id = 1:60,
                              row_id = 1:60,
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  
  #2  temp display filters df
  display.df <- reactiveValues(data=start.df)
  observeEvent(input$only_johns, {
    
    temp <- isolate(start.df$data)
    if (input$only_johns) {
      
      display.df$data <- temp[temp$userName == "John",]
    } else {
      display.df$data <- temp
    }
  })
  
  # Display editable datatable
  output$userTable <- renderDataTable({
    req(display.df$data)
    DT::datatable(isolate(display.df$data),
                  editable = TRUE,
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list(
                    columnDefs = list(
                      list(
                        visible = FALSE,
                        targets = 2
                      )
                    )
                  ))
  })
  
  ###Tracking Changes###
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy('userTable')

  observeEvent(input$userTable_cell_edit, {
    
    display.df$data <- editData(display.df$data, input$userTable_cell_edit, rownames = FALSE)
    DT::replaceData(proxy, display.df$data, rownames = FALSE, resetPaging = FALSE)
    
    # update the data in the original df
    # get the correct row_id
    curr_row_id <- display.df$data[input$userTable_cell_edit[["row"]], "row_id", drop = TRUE]
    # get the correct column position
    column_pos <- input$userTable_cell_edit[["col"]] + 1 # DT starts indexing at 0
    # update the data
    temp <- start.df$data
    temp[temp$row_id == curr_row_id, column_pos] <- input$userTable_cell_edit[["value"]]
    start.df$data <- temp
  })
  
  
  output$downloadResults <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste("userTest.csv", sep = "")},
    content = function(file){write.csv(start.df$data, file, row.names = FALSE)}
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Edit

Here is a version where the page gets not reset. The problem was that with the edited data, `display.df$data` was changed, which triggered the rerendering of `output$userTable` and this resetted the page. To circumvent this, I've added another reactive value that contains the edited data and don't change `display.df` anymore, it is only changed by changing the input filtering.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "demo")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    downloadButton("downloadResults","Download Results"),
    checkboxInput("only_johns", "only_johns")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = 'admin', class = 'active', 
      fluidRow(
        box(
          dataTableOutput('userTable'), width = 6
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'admin function test', header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  #1
  start.df <- reactiveValues(data=NA)
  start.df$data <- data.frame(userName = rep(c("John","Ida","Mike"),20),
                              id = 1:60,
                              row_id = 1:60,
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  
  #2  temp display filters df
  display.df <- reactiveValues(data=isolate(start.df))
  edit.df <- reactiveValues(data = isolate(start.df))
  observeEvent(input$only_johns, {
    
    temp <- isolate(start.df$data)
    if (input$only_johns) {
      
      display.df$data <- temp[temp$userName == "John",]
      edit.df$data <- temp[temp$userName == "John",]
    } else {
      display.df$data <- temp
      edit.df$data <- temp
    }
  })
  
  # Display editable datatable
  output$userTable <- renderDataTable({
    req(display.df$data)
    DT::datatable(display.df$data,
                  editable = TRUE,
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list(
                    columnDefs = list(
                      list(
                        visible = FALSE,
                        targets = 2
                      )
                    )
                  ))
  })
  
  ###Tracking Changes###
  
  proxy = dataTableProxy('userTable')

  observeEvent(input$userTable_cell_edit, {
    
    edit.df$data <- editData(edit.df$data, input$userTable_cell_edit, rownames = FALSE)
    DT::replaceData(proxy, edit.df$data, rownames = FALSE, resetPaging = FALSE)
    
    # update the data in the original df
    # get the correct row_id
    curr_row_id <- edit.df$data[input$userTable_cell_edit[["row"]], "row_id", drop = TRUE]
    # get the correct column position
    column_pos <- input$userTable_cell_edit[["col"]] + 1 # DT starts indexing at 0
    # update the data
    temp <- start.df$data
    temp[temp$row_id == curr_row_id, column_pos] <- input$userTable_cell_edit[["value"]]
    start.df$data <- temp
  })
  
  
  output$downloadResults <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste("userTest.csv", sep = "")},
    content = function(file){write.csv(start.df$data, file, row.names = FALSE)}
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That seems to work in general and thanks for the simplification! But the `resetPaging = FALSE` isn't respected. That is, if you change a value while on, say, page 4, then it jumps back to page 1. Do you know why?

Comment: Should work now, the `renderDataTable` was still reactive to changes in `display.df`. To be honest, I don't exactly know why it worked in your original code.

Comment: Excellent. This feels complicated, but it appears to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

__
Hello!

This post is very interesting.
I have used the same code above, but when I edit a cell, an error message occurs for users : "Warning : JSON invalid response" at each edition !

Everything seems correct. How can I delete this error message ?

I try this but it does not work :

```
tags$script(HTML("$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';")),
```

Many thanks for your collaboration,
Kind regards,